# Accessing running container (inside VM) from host OS

Tags: linux, docker, virtual-machine, docker-swarm, multipass

I have set up 3 Linux VM through [multipass](https://multipass.run/) on my host Mac OSX. I have installed docker on these machines and started a 3 node docker swarm.

```
docker swarm init
```

After that, I have created 2 services one is for Postgres DB and the other is for drupal with the following command.

```
docker service create -d --name postgras-db --network test-swarm-network -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=<password> postgres

docker service create -d  --name drupal-frontend --network test-swarm-network -p 80:80 drupal
```

Port 80:80 is exposed for drupal and both of these services are connected to the same overlay network. My services are up and running.

If I am doing everything on the host machine then I will simply do http://localhost:80 or http://localhost to get the desired output but now when running it in VM how I can test the drupal front from host MAC, i.e which IP to hit in the host browser to get the desired result.

P.S: There is nothing specific here about drupal (it could be any other container like Nginx etc), the question is about accessing running container (inside VM) from host OS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out myself. For other help:

We can get the info of a running VM by running the following command on host machine.

```
multipass info <VM_Name>
```

like

```
multipass info docker-vm
```

it will give the info about the VM which also contains the IP on which VM is running

```
multipass info docker-vm
Name:           docker-vm 
State:          Running
IPv4:           192.168.xx.x
                172.xx.x.x
Release:        Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Image hash:     3d7282d3e92b (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS)
Load:           0.08 0.15 0.09
Disk usage:     2.2G out of 4.7G
Memory usage:   264.6M out of 976.9M
```

From here user can copy the IP address and paste it into the host browser which will hit port 80 (by default) of the VM.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use below command:

```
 docker exec -it container_name /bin/bash
```

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it.

Comment: The question was related to how i check my frontend in the browser, as far as running commands on the VM i am already able to do that. 
I was interested in the IP address of the VM which i can access from the host OS.